# NSIS - Merge Modules

Tags: installation, nsis, merge-module

I'm looking for away to include into the installation the merge modules of VC2008 (mscrt90 and atl90) 
My main problem involved around bundling the policy file. I've no problem adding the DLL and the manifest files but the policy seems to behave differently and can not simply be copied over...

The best solution I came up with so far was to include the MSM files into a separate MSI that is being installed by the NSIS script. But this is an ugly solution.

Thanks,
Eden

Answer (score 7):

NSIS is not a good solution for this.  NSIS has no support for merge modules whatsoever.  If you are looking for a free open source solution, try using Windows Installer XML (WiX, http://wix.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 1):

If your installer is not MSI based, why use merge modules at all?

Your Visual Studio install should have a redist folder with exe files you can use to install the CRT etc

Comment: Because I try to minimize the installation file. The provided add around 4mb while the necessary dll's are only 750kb.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the merge modules to include the installation you can use the official visual studio redistributable installer. They can be called from the nsis script in the installation process with silent mode.

Answer (score 0):

I found this on NSIS forums: `msiexec /i foo.msm /qn'` but did not had time to test it yet. Clearly I will do it.

Note: obviously you need `msiexec` which may be missing on ancient versions of Windows, but probably you should not support these anymore.

Comment: I tested it and it does not work. At least not for the msm redistrubutable package for intel fortran 2013_sp1.